# Samba server not starting on boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba

I've got an Ubuntu server. I installed Samba to share files with Windows clients and it started off fine. I recently added some shares that are based on UnionFS and now the samba server will not start at boot and I have to launch it manually (`/etc/init.d/samba start` works without error)

It's annoying and it's going to cause problems when the server gets restarted when I'm not there. Can anybody suggest an idea why it's not booting and/or give me a way to make sure it does.

Edit: Just restarted. Here's the log for the boot-up.

```
[2009/05/15 10:04:21,  0] smbd/server.c:main(1260)
  smbd version 3.3.2 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2009
[2009/05/15 10:04:21,  0] printing/print_cups.c:cups_connect(103)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused
[2009/05/15 10:04:21,  0] printing/print_cups.c:cups_connect(103)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused
[2009/05/15 10:04:21,  0] lib/interface.c:load_interfaces(546)
  WARNING: no network interfaces found
[2009/05/15 10:04:22,  0] smbd/server.c:open_sockets_smbd(554)
  open_sockets_smbd: No sockets available to bind to.
```

I realise I need to clean out some CUPS nonsense.. The "no network interfaces" part is really odd because it will start up (albeit manually).

Here's the log when I run `/etc/init.d/samba start`

```
[2009/05/15 10:09:03,  0] smbd/server.c:main(1260)
  smbd version 3.3.2 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2009
```

No grief about CUPS. No moaning about network interfaces. No nagging about sockets. How I like it.

Comment: Just looking at those logs, could it be the network adapter not being connected before samba starts? I'm specifying it in the conf. I'll turn that off and give it another go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked to see that you have all these links ?

```
/etc/rc5.d/S20samba
/etc/rc4.d/S20samba
/etc/rc3.d/S20samba
/etc/rc2.d/S20samba
```

If not, then samba is not set to autostart, and you should set it up to do so with something like :

`update-rc.d samba defaults`

Edit:

Ok, so what is reported in the log files around system start up time ?

```
/var/log/samba/log.smbd
/var/log/samba/log.nmbd
```

check those two and see if there's anything suspicious in there.

Comment: Yeah they already exist. I ran the command anyway but just got: "System startup links for /etc/init.d/samba already exist."

Comment: Edited to show logs.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it is most likely going to fix things for the next person that comes in this thread with a faulty samba set up.

Answer (score 2):

> I recently added some shares that are
>   based on UnionFS and now the samba
>   server will not start at boot and I
>   have to launch it manually

When and how do these UnionFS things get mounted?  Are they all done in the /etc/fstab, or do you have some script that mounts them.  The important question is are they mounted before the system attempts to start Samba?

Comment: Very good point, I'd not thought of that.

Comment: They're mounted in fstab so I can't see how they'd not be mounted by the time samba was loading.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Bother.

I turned out that the whole problem was caused by me binding to an interface that (apparently) isn't set up until after Samba starts.

Sorry for all the red herrings and thank you both for your answers.